# Symbol timing synchronization with delay

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I’m trying to simulate a TLL loop using Gardner TED. I set symbol rate is 1000 and 8 samples for 1 symbol. First I use Root-raised-cosine filter to shape the symbols, then I use interp1 in matlab to resample the signal to add sampling delay. And then I feed the signal to the match filter, then I downsample the signal to four points for 1 symbol in that the interpolator needs 4 points as input, then I downsample these 4 points to 2 points because the TED only needs two samples for 1 symbol, after this I send the matched signal to the loop. I didn’t drop the filter delay because I use it as what happens in the real world, that is, we don’t know when the symbol starts. It works fine at first the fractional interval converges to a value, but when I change the number of delay before the signal it won’t converge. For instance, if I increase or decrease the number of random value before the signal, the loop won’t be stable. [image]
When it converges [image]
When it doesn’t converge [image]
Should I add a frame synchronization unit before TED? I think the structure of RX would be match filter then symbol timing synchronization next carrier recovery and finally be the frame synchronization.

Comment: You don't need frame sync for Gardner to work. From your description, you're doing things correctly, so it's probably a bug in your code. To make sure your understanding is correct, I recommend reading Gardner's original paper; it's very approachable, and the sync algorithm can implemented directly from the description there.

Comment: It may be that your loop bandwidth is just too high. The plot doesn't appear to be unstable but instead passing a lot of the high self-noise the Gardner TED has on a sample by sample basis (the TED output directly is quite noisy). Reduce significantly the gain constant in your loop to confirm this. Then increase the gain to balance settling time and noise. Further optimization requires a more detailed understanding of control loops and proper loop filter design.